# Div scrolling to top instead of scrolling to bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, scroll

I want my div to scroll to bottom .  I have tried many codes which involves scrollTop and ScrollHeight but it does not seem to work. When I use those codes then the div scrolls to top instead of bottom. What should I do

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="manager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateComments" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div id="currentinfo"
         style="height: 742px; width: 612px; overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;">

      <asp:Literal ID="RecepientConversation" runat="server" />

    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExitChatRoom" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I used this code But div once coming to bottom again goes to top

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function () { 
                         var elem = document.getElementById('currentinfo'); 
                         elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight; 
                       }, 
                       5000)
</script>
```

Comment: try to use overflow:scroll in place of overflow:hiden

Comment: That is for horizontal scollBar, And I am talking about vertical scrollbar

Comment: did you try using pageload? `<script>function pageLoad(){ var elem = document.getElementById('currentinfo'); elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;  }</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myScrollDiv").animate({ scrollTop: $('#myScrollDiv')[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);
    });

</script>
```

This Is Your Div

```
<div id="myScrollDiv"  style='overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;max-height:200px;'>
 Test Test Test <br/>
                 <br/>
                 <br/>
</div>
```